# Cakephp Blog Tutorial - Add Routine

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I followed the cakePHP Blog Tutorial and I have a logical error happened in the `cakephp/posts/add` Routine

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html

I got the default `cakephp/posts/add` Routine from the tutorial working just fine, but when I duplicate the routine and try to rename it to `cakephp/apples/add` (Posts to Apples) it seems that `$this->Apple->save($this->request->data)` and `$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'))` is not working it just refreshes me the page and doesn't redirect to the index view and doesn't save the record also.

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('apple')) {
        $this->Apple->create();
        if ($this->Apple->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
    }
}
```

what would be the possible problem in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies at this line:

`if ($this->request->is('apple')) {`

You are checking for the type of request to determine if it is a form submission (usually POST), hence it should instead be

`if ($this->request->is('post')) {`

Answer (score 0):

Ypu should handle request with `$this->request->is('post');` or `$this->request->is('get');` and if you want use different model in default controller like in PostsController want to use Apple model you need load this model in controller like `$this->loadModel('Apple');` or define in $uses variable like `public $uses = array('Post', 'Apple')`;